# Use of a swift dictionary returns all its values?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have the swift dictionary `myD`, that has enums of type `myEnum` as keys, and `()` functions as values.
When I try the function of one of the keys, all functions get called. Please Help. Here's the code below:

```
class myScene: SKScene {
    enum myEnum {
        case one
        case two
    }

    func foo1() { print(1) }
    func foo2() { print(2) }

    var myD: [myEnum : ()] {
        return [
            .one : foo1(),
            .two : foo2()
        ]
    }

    func runFuncForCase(_ ca: myEnum) {
            myD[ca]
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        runFuncForCase(.one) //HERE!!!!!
    }
```

}

When I run the app, wether I put `.one` or `.two` in the `runFuncForCase(_:)` function, the consle always prints "1" and "2", which means both functions did run.

Comment: `runFuncForCase[.one]` doesn't compile. You probably mean `runFuncForCase(.one)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With this declaration of your dictionary, the value type of the Dictionary is `Void`, which can contain only empty tuple `()`.

```
var myD: [myEnum : ()] {
    return [
        .one : foo1(),
        .two : foo2()
    ]
}
```

And `foo1()` and `foo2()` are evaluated when `myD`'s getter is called. Not after subscript to `myD`. (And their return types are `Void`, so they are considered as returning empty tuples.)

You may need to write something like this:

```
class myScene: SKScene {
    enum myEnum {
        case one
        case two
    }

    func foo1() { print(1) }
    func foo2() { print(2) }

    var myD: [myEnum : ()->Void] { //### value type of the dictionary needs to be a function type
        return [
            .one : foo1,    //### actual value of the dictionary needs to be a function itself,
            .two : foo2,    // not the result of calling the function
        ]
    }

    func runFuncForCase(_ ca: myEnum) {
        myD[ca]!()   //### To invoke the function, you need `()`
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        runFuncForCase(.one)
    }
}
```

---

**Some caution to be noted**

The code above is a little bit simplified, that it's ignoring the risk of creating retain cycles, as instance methods implicitly hold strong reference of `self`.

In actual apps, you should:

- Make `foo1` and `foo2` top-level functions

or

- Write something like this:

  ```
  var myD: [myEnum : ()->Void] {
      return [
          .one : {[weak self] in self?.foo1()},
          .two : {[weak self] in self?.foo2()},
      ]
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly. Until I added the `{[weak self] in ....() }`. It started giving me an error.

Comment: @Fayyouz, sorry, it was too early to append that part. (My Xcode is so slow to show errors...) You need to prefix `self` to call instance methods inside escaping closures. Please try the edited code, and tell me if you get other errors.